# Rails style fixture deserializer for c#

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, fixtures

Is there an open source deserializer in C# that could read a RoR style fixture into a given type? I tried googling it, but there really was not much that came up. It seems like a really simple thing that someone else has probably already done.

Example fixture file:

temperature_readings.yml

```
one:
  CelciusReading: 9.99

two:
  CelciusReading: 23
```

Library call:

```
Dictionary<String, TemperatureReading> readings = Fixture.Get<TemperatureReading>("temperature_readings.yml");
```

Expected output would be something like:

```
  readings = new []{
      {
       Key = "one",
       Value = new TemperatureReading { CelciusReading = 9.99 }
      },
      {
       Key = "two",
       Value = new TemperatureReading { CelciusReading = 23 }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a library released under the MIT license called YamlSerializer.

https://yamlserializer.codeplex.com/